# show this inequality to $\sum_{cyc} \frac {a^3b}{(3a+2b)^3} \ge \sum_{cyc} \frac {a^2bc}{(2a+2b+c)^3} $

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers. Prove that
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac {a^3b}{(3a+2b)^3} \ge \sum_{cyc} \frac {a^2bc}{(2a+2b+c)^3} $$

This problem is from Iran 3rd round-2017-Algebra final exam-P3,Now I can't find this inequality have solve it,maybe  it seem can use  integral to solve it?

my attempts:

I took $p=3a+2b,$ $2a+2b+c$. $k=3$  and I wanted to use this integral:
$$\dfrac{1}{p^k}=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(k)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^{k-1}e^{-pt}dt$$
but I don't see how it  helps.

Comment: I think it was a typo in the formulation. This inequality is true, but has a very ugly solution. The inequality with nice solution is the following. $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3b}{(2a+3b)^3}\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2bc}{(2a+2b+c)^3}.$

Comment: can you post your nice solution with $\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^3b}{(2a+3b)^3}\ge\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^2bc}{(2a+2b+c)^3}$?Thanks

Comment: Yes of course. But you need before to show us your attempts. If you'll make it and  this topic not would be closed, I'll post my solution in the evening. I found here something, which really is very nice.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg,I have add mu attempts,and take $p=3a+2b$,$2a+2b+c$.$k=3$,maybe can help?

Comment: This inequality is obviously true by BW, but this solution is not by hand.

Comment: Also, this inequality is obviously true after full expanding by AM-GM. But for the proof we need to use a computer again.

Comment: By C-S we can get an  inequality with degree $11$, but it's still very ugly.

Answer (score 6):

The proof of my inequality.

> let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
>   $$\tfrac{a^3b}{(2a+3b)^3}+\tfrac{b^3c}{(2b+2c)^3}+\tfrac{c^3a}{(2c+3a)^3}\geq\tfrac{a^2bc}{(2a+2b+c)^3}+\tfrac{b^2ca}{(2b+2c+a)^3}+\tfrac{c^2ab}{(2c+2a+b)^3}.$$

Indeed, by Holder and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{a^3b}{(2a+3b)^3}=\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{\left(4(2a+3b)+(2b+3c)+2(2c+3a)\right)^3\left(\tfrac{4a^3b}{(2a+3b)^3}+\tfrac{b^3c}{(2b+3c)^3}+\tfrac{2c^3a}{(2c+3a)^3}\right)}{2401(2a+2b+c)^3}\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{\left(4\sqrt[4]{a^3b}+\sqrt[4]{b^3c}+2\sqrt[4]{c^3a}\right)^4}{2401(2a+2b+c)^3}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{\left(7\sqrt[28]{a^{12+2}b^{4+3}c^{1+6}}\right)^4}{2401(2a+2b+c)^3}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2bc}{(2a+2b+c)^3}.$$

Answer (score -1):

Using binomial inequality for
$$|c-a|<2a+2b+c,$$
one can get
$$\dfrac1{(3a+2b)^3}=\dfrac1{(2a+2b+c)^3}\left(1-\dfrac{c-a}{2a+2b+c}\right)^{-3}
\ge \dfrac1{(2a+2b+c)^3}\left(1+3\dfrac{c-a}{2a+2b+c}\right),$$
$$\dfrac{a^3b}{(3a+2b)^3}-\dfrac{a^2bc}{(2a+2b+c)^3} \ge \dfrac{a^2b}{(2a+2b+c)^3}\left(a-c-3a\dfrac{c-a}{2a+2b+c}\right),\tag1$$
The issue inequality can be presented in the form of
$$S\ge 0\tag2,$$
where
$$S = \sum\limits_\bigcirc \left(\dfrac{a^3b}{(3a+2b)^3}-\dfrac{a^2bc}{(2a+2b+c)^3}\right) \ge  \sum\limits_\bigcirc\dfrac{a^2b(a-c)}{(2a+2b+c)^3}
+3\sum\limits_\bigcirc\dfrac{a^3b(a-c)}{(2a+2b+c)^4}.$$

In according with the rearrangement inequality for the productions of 
$$a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot \dfrac b{2a+2b+c}
+ b\cdot b\cdot b\cdot \dfrac c{2b+2c+a}
+ c\cdot c\cdot c\cdot \dfrac a{2c+2a+b}$$
and
$$a\cdot a\cdot c\cdot \dfrac b{2a+2b+c}
+ b\cdot b\cdot a\cdot \dfrac c{2b+2c+a}
+ c\cdot c\cdot b\cdot \dfrac a{2c+2a+b}$$
between $a$ and $c$ (where the ratio can be placed arbitrary), one can write
$$\sum\limits_\bigcirc\dfrac{a^3b}{(2a+2b+c)^3} \ge
\sum\limits_\bigcirc\dfrac{a^2bc}{(2a+2b+c)^3}$$
and similarly
$$\sum\limits_\bigcirc\dfrac{a^4b}{(2a+2b+c)^4} \ge
\sum\limits_\bigcirc\dfrac{a^3bc}{(2a+2b+c)^4},$$
so $(1)$ is valid.

$\textbf{Proved.}$

Comment: To which numbers exactly is the rearrangement inequality applied?

Comment: @MartinR To subsequences $\{a,a\}$ and $\{c.c\}.$

Comment: Well, perhaps I am too dumb to see it. The rearrangement inequality states that $x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 + x_3 y_3$ is maximal if $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $(y_1, y_2, y_3)$ are ordered in the same way (both ascending or both descending). What are  $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $(y_1, y_2, y_3)$  in your case so that the final two inequalities are obtained?

Comment: @MartinR I think that the most clear way is to correspond the debominators with $b.$

Comment: Is it so difficult to give a clear answer? Something like  *“The rearrangement inequality is applied to $x_1 = \ldots, x_2 = \ldots $ etc, therefore ...”*  ?

Comment: @MartinR Thabk you for the productive discussion. Will be done.

Comment: @Yuri Negometyanov Explain please, how you used Rearrangement. I saw your correspondence with Martin R. I did not see the answer. Thank you! Also, if you'll see down-voting, it's not mine.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg You are welcome! Using [this link](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=598&lmm=0), I see non-decreasing sequences $\{a,a\}$ and then $\{c,c\}$ in the sum of productions in the LHS and its permutations in the RHS. BTW, MartinR never stops dialogue if he has doubts.

Comment: @Yuri Negometyanov Can you write sequences, for which you used Rearrangement. Your sequences $(a,a)$ and $(c,c)$  give $a^2+c^2\geq2ac$, which is true, but it's nothing here. Actually, components of sequences should be ordered, otherwise Rearrangement does not work.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Done.

Comment: Read please about Rearrangement.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Read my answer, please. If the permutaation changes non-decreasing order,then it decreases the sum.

Comment: Also, your  $(1)$ is wrong for $a>c$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Is it a joke?  The task has cyclic symmetry.

Comment: It's not joke. It's wrong. If you want to write the cyclic sum, so you can do it. But you did not write it. Your $(1)$ is wrong and not follows from the previous. Why the cyclic versa will be true?  I think your solution is total wrong.

Comment: (1) is wrong because within the last parentheses, it should be $a-c + 3a\dfrac{c-a}{2a+2b+c}$.

Comment: However, (after correcting this error) $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \dfrac{a^2b}{(2a+2b+c)^3}\left(a-c+ 3a\dfrac{c-a}{2a+2b+c}\right) \ge 0$ is wrong.